# Facebook sharer URL cannot post to group when accessing through mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, share

I am using the Facebook sharer URL like this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com

When clicking the link (browser), I am able to share to my own timeline, to a friend in a message or to a group.

But when accessing through my mobile, I only have the option to post on my own timeline.

How do I enable group-sharing through mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add m2w then it uses the desktop version instead of mobile site, adding the options you wanted.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?m2w&u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com